# Regex difference between a simple negative lookbehind and a 'not' character class

Tags: regex

Compare `[^,]"` with `(?<!,)"`

How are these expressions different? Don't they both say "Give me all the double quotes not preceded by the comma character?"

What are the situations where they return different results?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a lookbehind and a negated character class is this:

- A lookbehind **does not** get captured in the match result; it is just a requirement of the match in order for it to become true. `(?<!,)"` means quote cannot be preceded by comma, and may or may not be preceded by any other character.
- A negated character class rather, is *included* in the match result. `[^,]"` means it will **require** a character before the quote and will match so long as it is not a comma.

Comment: @digitgopher not entirely, the fact that it isn't included in the match result is the other major difference.

Comment: So is the start of a line the only case where there is a difference if you only care about number of matches found, not what is returned from each?

Answer (score 1):

`[^,]"` matches all the double quotes present after to any character but not of comma. This matches also the previous non-comma character. And also this regex won't match the double quotes which was present at the start of a line. `[^,]` must consume a character, because there isn't a character before the `"` present at the start, this regex must fail to match the quotes present at the start.

`(?<!,)"`  matches all the double quotes present after to any character but not of comma and it won't match the previous non-comma character. And this also matches double quotes which was present at the start of a line. Lookarounds are just an assertions, it won't match any character but it asserts whether the match is possible or not.